# iPad to send Serial (Rs-232) commands to RPi

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I need to connect a mac / windows / iPad client to a Pi that has 4 UART RS-232 devices attached to it. The client will send the serial command, and then Pi will the forward them to the devices.

What are the options to connect to the Pi that will work across all clients?

I was thinking bluetooth the best option for this? But I have read that Apple may restrict this to just audio, and controlling devices you have to join the MFi program.  Is this correct?

Can you connect direct to a Pi with wifi?  or this is only supported over a network?

Is a a wired cable option the only way?

Comment: At work, I use a server socket written in Python on the RPi. Then on the iOS devices, we connect to that socket and communicate with it.

Comment: @Brandon, how does the device connect to the RPi, is it via DNS / over a network?

Answer (score 0):

The Serial transport may make sense for low-cost accessories that do not need to transmit audio, or for device-powered accessories which emphasize low power draw over high data transmission rates. Otherwise,the USB Host Mode transport is recommended,So you can use the usb transport method (lightning connect Configuration C: Serial)